As or no as in the following sentences?
As John Lennon once said, life is what happens to you while you're busy making other plans.
As Albert Einstein once said, ''not everything that counts, and not everything that's counted truly counts. ''
Say is transitive. I am an ESL Chinese learner preparing for NMET (Chinese English Gaokao, National Matriculation English Test), and I saw those sentences on my workbook. I wonder if they are correct, or, from my POV, should be revised as As was said by sb or just be without As? The As was done by sb structure is classified as nonrestrictive relative clause in grammar book jargons.
There is the phrase As a saying goes. I deem it right because go is intransitive. But the examples above make me nonplussed.
Another presumption: Perhaps they are casual usage and also well-established. For example, I saw what time appears in Doulingo app and then looked it up, finding that it's a substitute for At what time or When. Is my assumption right that As is justified in the sentences above but just in casual usage?
Additionally, is there any difference for the quote mark in the examples?
Thanks if you would be so kind as to explain this.

The Einstein one is not a stand-alone sentence. [as *the saying goes, not: a]. "As x once said" is 100% accurate and standard English. "as was done by x" is passive and would not be used to refer to what someone says. There would have to be a very good reason for a passive phrasing like that.

@Lambie I looked up merriam and found say indeed can be intransitive, synonymous with speak. As sb speaks (this is a clause), sb does sth (this part us the main sentence). Does this make sense?

@Lambie Let's parse the sentence. As sb says, sb does sth. (yes, end quote, and period). From grammar book I know that As and be used to start a relative clause and take the place of the object or subject in a sentence. Different from which, As can start a sentence (thus capitalized). As can mean when, and when does not make sense here. As then becomes a relative pronoun. The pronoun should refer to an antecedent or a whole sentence. In this case, the quote following then becomes what As refers to. But since I can rarely find intransitive say usage in merriam webster corpus,

I don't think the sentence is complete. First, Sb says sth is correct sentence, and only the sth is in the form of an object clause. It means that the whole clause is the object. The Lennon example is not exact quote, but we can learn from context the part after say is the object of it (the transitive verb say). So do you think As plus SVO structure is a complete sentence? SVO alone is a complete sentence. And when you use As, it becomes a adverbial clause. (It's not correct to omit the main part of a sentence.) So I think As as gratuitous here.

Just look at the passive and active: as X said VERSUS as was said by X. Forget speak here. Not relevant. Also, not totally synonymous.

As there means like: Like I said, As I said. In terms of meaning.  No, as is not gratuitous. Yes, adverbial. I wonder if the Einstein quote is a bit odd but it does work as a quote.

@lambieThanks. Well, I browsed more and found more As sb said+quote examples. I realized as is actually the object of the transitive verb say. The relative clause with as  also works here. As, the relative pronoun, then refers to the main sentence, i.e., the quote. Then the sentence is complete. Thanks again.

@Lambie Like I said is not parsable. E.g. Like I said, I couldn't understand. First, like is informal when used as a conjunction. Also, I can't find the object for the transitive verb say because the following part I couldn't understand is obviously not exact quote and thus does not become the object of say. It is the main part while Like I said is just a clause. Third, like cannot function as As to form a relative clause. Then said can be revised as thought or meant, both of which can be intransitive.

I was explaining the meaning of as in "as I said".  BUT this:  ''Not everything that counts, and not everything that's counted, truly counts.'' works fine. The entire thing is the quote and a stand-alone sentence. And that sentence, as I have edited it, now works FINE in English. There was a missing comma. There is a double subject. See? :)

@Lambie First, according to the like entry (a conjunction) on OALD, the usage, like I said is correct. It's equivalent to as (=in the way in which) I said before. Second, according to OALD say, it can be intransitive in phrase like can't say. So Like I said is both established and can be parsed in that case. Third, while the world-class pronoun is not included in OALD, it is included in Merriam Webster, which is synonymous with that or which. And as is used after a the same or such-modified noun.

@ishtar I used Sogou (an engine good at searching Chinese contents) to search as, relative clause, relative pronouns, and relative adverbs. Those tutorials usually sort as as a relative pronoun. And from my view, if as is not seen as a pronoun, as was said by sb, or as it's known to all will make no sense.  Then I searched the same on Bing. (I can't access to Quora because I have no VPN.) It's strange that as is included in neither relative pronouns nor relative adverbs. And no results were found regarding how to use as in a relative clause.

To conclude, I wonder, while ESL learners focus on how to parse sentences when learning English from scratch, why do native speakers seldom do so? On one hand, perhaps to call things by their right names and memorize grammar jargons is not the sensible way. Then how does such method not work for native speakers? E.g. I spot run-on sentences and I've to mean I possess. And they are both wrong. On the other hand, parsing doesn't work for idiomatic phrases like in the way that (=in the way in which) and what time (=when). Then how do those grammar concepts matter to those exceptions?

Please stop writing such long comments to me. The question was not about say, it's was about the Einstein quote. I answered that above and you did not respond. [jargon is singular there]. If you want to discuss all these other things, go to the chat room and ping me. (fyi, I'm leaving for this week in two hours but after that.)

If you say, "Bob said, X", you are telling the audience that Bob made this statement. That sentence by itself gives no indication whether you think that X is true or false.
If you say, "As Bob said, X", you are telling the audience that X is a true statement.
To make a simple example: If I said, "Bob said Mary stole the money", I am telling you that Bob CLAIMED that Mary stole it. I may or may not believe Bob. Bob himself may not be sure. But if I say, "As Bob said, Mary stole the money", then I am telling you that Bob claimed that Mary stole it, AND that Bob is correct.
RE do the quotes make a difference? Yes. If you put quotes around text in a context like this, that tells the reader that these are the exact words that the person said or wrote. If you don't put quotes, that means that this is the general idea but not necessary the exact words.
Like if Bob said, exact quote, "These are the times that try men's souls", I could write:
Bob said, "These are the times that try men's souls."
Or I could write:
Bob said these are trying times for men's souls.
(Or many other variations.)
Side note: Your Einstein quote doesn't make sense. "Not everything that counts". What about the things that count? Perhaps the real quote is something more like, "Not everything counts, and not everything that's counted ..." etc?

Not everything that can be counted counts, and not everything that counts can be counted.
1,646 Views
Albert Einstein

from quotes.net

RE do the quotes make a difference? What does RE stand for? I can't find this acronym.

"Re" is not an acronym, it is a Latin word that we use in English to mean "regarding" or "on the subject of".  It is the same word that email programs add to the beginning of the subject line when you reply to an email.
